# Using strings that represent instance variable in a python class to grab the value

Tags: python, instance-variables, accessor

```
class Thing(object):
  def __init__(self, array):
    self.a = array[0]
    self.b = array[1]
    self.c = array[2]
```

I have a list of Thing objects, each of which has a set of values. I'm trying to compute a histogram of the frequency distributions of the values contains in a,b,c, and so I have a script that basically does:

```
hist = dict()
for t in things:
    if t.a not in hist.keys():
        hist[s.a] = 0
    else:
        hist[s.a] += 1
```

However, I want to be able to generalize the code so that I have a local dict that stores the frequency of a, then the frequency of b. I can do this really easily in ruby by just reading in a CSV file (this is where the Thing attributes are coming from, I created a class because I have had problems in the past creating scripts that are not amenable to subsequent changes because they are so ad-hoc.

```
f = File.open('trainingdatatostudents.csv')
lines = f.readlines
attributes = lines[0]
attributes = attributes.split(",")
records = []
1.upto(10).each {|num|
    hist = Hash.new(0)
    name = ""
    lines.each {|line|
        elements = line.split(",")

        records.push(elements[num])
        hist[elements[num]] += 1
    }
    puts hist
}
```

I know that I can use the **dict** variable that is in every instance of a class, but then I just have the values as strings, and I can't do something like s."a" so how do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Example of input file and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this what you're looking for?

```
>>> things = [Thing([1,2,3]), Thing([4,5,6]), Thing([1,4,3])]
>>> things[0].__dict__
{'c': 3, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> for t in things:
    for att in t.__dict__:
        getattr(t, att)
```

Output is :

```
3
1
2
6
4
5
3
1
4
```

Added in, just for sake of complete clarity (I did understand you right? you want a histogram of the values stored in the Thing object attributes?)
You could do

```
hist = []
for t in things:
    for att in t.__dict__:
        hist.append(getattr(t, att))
```

and then to not bother yourself use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
hist = np.hist(hist, bins=5)
>>> hist
(array([2, 1, 2, 2, 2]), array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.]))
```

First array are bin heights, second bin values. Or you could just plot it directly in matplotlib.pyplot hist function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time understanding what you're looking for exactly, but you said you could do it really easy in ruby. Here's the same code, but in python:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open('trainingdatatostudents.csv') as openfile:
    reader = csv.reader(openfile)
    headers = reader.readline()
    records = []
    for i in range(10):
        hist = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
        for line in reader:
            records.append(line[i])
            hist[records[i]] += 1
        print hist
```

This pulls straight from the csv. Not sure where you're going to go with the information.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

def hasNumbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)

class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line
        self.id = line[0]
        self.ct = line[1]
        self.ucsz = line[2]
        self.ucsh = line[3]
        self.ma = line[4]
        self.sec = line[5]
        self.bn = line[6]
        self.bc = line[7]
        self.nn = line[8]
        self.m = line[9]
        self.ok = line[10]

    def __str__(self):
        return "id: " + str(self.id) + ", ct: " + str(self.ct) + ", ucsz: " + str(self.ucsz) + ", ucsh: " + str(self.ucsh) + ", ma: " + str(self.ma) + ", sec: " + str(self.sec) + ", bn: " + str(self.bn) + ", bc: " + str(self.bc) + ", nn: " + str(self.nn) + ", m: " + str(self.m) + ", ok: " + str(self.ok)

x = []
pp = ""
with open('desk/trainingdatatostudents.csv') as f:
    flag = False
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        if flag is False:
            pp = row
            flag = True
        else:
            x.append(Student(row))
print pp
q = []
count = 1
for val in range(1,11):
    hist = dict()   
    for s in x:
        if hasNumbers(s.line[val]) and int(s.line[val]) not in hist.keys():
            hist[int(s.line[val])] = 0
        elif hasNumbers(s.line[val]):
            hist[int(s.line[val])] += 1 
    print(pp[count] + str(hist))
    count = count + 1
```

This code does what I want it to, just wanted to share. I just decided to give my student an array instance variable and it just made my life easier.